# JSON Not Working on IIS8 Deployed Application

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a working MVC5 Web application, when am debugging on VS it works perfectly well and pull all Json formatted files to dropdown box very well.

But When I Deployed the application on IIS8 the Json refused to pull to my nested dropdown when choose, So am I missing any configuration for it to work on my localhost(IIS)? I will really appreciate any help thanks.

I checked on my browser debugger and found out that it returning a 404 Not Found error on the javascript console, But this is the same application that am lunching on VS and it working fine... Please am kind of confuse any help please?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js?

Comment: If you press F12 in your browser you will be able to see what the response was from the server if there was ever a request sent.

Comment: Yea that's, I have 404 not found error listed in my Java script console... Why will it happen like that when already working with VS without any error

Comment: Almost certainly because you have hard coded the url. Always use `var url = '@Url.Action("yourActionName", "yourControllerName")';` to generate the correct url

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relative path on url from where you have called the function through JSON in your view page.

Like as below:

```
var urlRelative = '<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>';
                $.getJSON(urlRelative, function (sourceData) {
                    var select = $("#SourceInfoComboBox1");
                    select.empty();

                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: null,
                        text: "-Select-"
                    }));


$.each(sourceData, function (index, itemData) {
                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));
                });

        });
```